# Run instance of google chrome in background

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, xvfb

I'm trying to run Google Chrome from terminal, and while it's running (my chrome extension will be navigating and extracting data) I want it to be invisible to the user. some kind of headless running.

Xvfb doesn't work in that case (the window is opening and visible to the user)

the google-chrome arg --no-startup-window just starts the process but not the browser.

could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, runnig Chrome headless is impossible. You should run Chrome inside any display. I confused a bit by your statement

> Xvfb doesn't work in that case (the window is opening and visible to
>   the user)

Because we are also using Xvfb for this purpose, and it is NOT visible for user - simply because this display is not known for the user. Maybe you are running Chrome not inside of Xvfb, but inside of user's display? Did you export DISPLAY variable for newly created Xvfb display? This code should work perfectly:

```
Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0 1280x1024x16
export DISPLAY=:99
chromium
```

after that, you will have chromium opened on display :99 (inside Xvbf) and not visible for user.